# Mass Remove File Prefix on a Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, rename, batch-rename

How do I mass remove file prefixes in a Mac? For example, inside my folder, I have the following files:

```
img_sometext1.jpg
img_sometext2.jpg
...
img_sometext10.jpg
```

How do I remove `img_`?

Comment: best answer https://superuser.com/a/1400717/16871

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The easiest solution might be to use the commercial [A Better Finder Rename](https://www.publicspace.net/ABetterFinderRename/) to achieve this.

For a free alternative, you can install the command-line `rename` utility:

- install [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/)
- install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)
- open Terminal.app and do `brew install rename`

You can now use, in the Terminal, either of:

```
rename -d img_ *
rename "s/^img_//" *
```

to strip away the prefix.

Comment: Awesome! I already had homebrew installed and your solution worked perfectly well.

Comment: So amazing, this is just the tool I needed

Comment: beautiful! How is it not easier to find brew casks such as `rename`?

Comment: It's got renamed all the files in seconds

Answer (score 11):

You can use Automator's *Rename Finder Items* action:

1. Start Automator, select *Workflow*, and add *Get Specified Finder Items* and *Rename Finder Items* from the library on the left to the workflow area on the right by double-clicking.
2. Drag and drop the files you want to rename to the list in *Get Specified Finder Items*.
3. Change *Rename Finder Items* to *Replace Text* as desired, and click the *Run* button.

[image: Automator screenshot]

Result after execution: [image: Result]

You can easily change this workflow to make it repeatable, e.g. with selected Finder items instead, and save it as Application or Service.

Answer (score 8):

A quick visit from the year 2019 to give an update.

osX has something like this built into finder now.

- Open finder
- Select all the files you want renamed
- From the right-click menu (or File menu) choose the `Rename # items` option
- You'll be presented with a dialog window with options, one of which is `Replace Text`
- Enter your prefix - "img_" in the `Find` box and leave the `Replace` box empty
- Click Rename

Answer (score 2):

If you want an elegant, easy, and feature-rich solution, I personally like [Name Mangler](http://manytricks.com/namemangler/).

Used to be called File List and was free, now it costs $10. May be a little steep for some people, but it's well-written and extremely functional if you don't want to get into the command-line methods of doing this.